# Why is my section element not showing as part of the body?

Tags: html, css

The section element is shown not contained in the body even though it's added inside the body in the html. The reason being that I set the width of the section to 500px and floated it to the right because i plan on adding content directly to the left of it. Is there any way to leave the section on the right but also within the body?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #5cdb95;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #379683;
  color: #05386B
}


/* Styling for the header */

header {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #379683;
  padding: 1.5em 0;
}


/* Styling for the nav bar */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #379683;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #05386B;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Styling for main content */

main {
  clear: left;
}

#missionStatement {
  text-align: center;
}

#missionStatement h1 {
  margin-top: 2em;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#missionStatement p {
  margin: 1em 2em;
}

section {
  width: 500px;
  float: right;
}

section h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <h1>Site name and Logo</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <h3>Home</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <h3>Learn</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <h3>Donate</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <h3>Empty</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div id="missionStatement">
      <h1>Mission Statement</h1>
      <p>Our goal is to teach individuals, especially youth, on how their actions affect the environment and how to lead greener lives and create a green place to live!
      </p>
    </div>
    <section>
      <h1>About us</h1>
      <p>
        Established in 2015, our goal is to empower individuals, especially youth, to lead in the response to climate change and other environmental challenges facing South Florida.. We assist diverse organizations, including schools, households, local governments
        and businesses to reduce their environmental footprint. Through establishing partnerships in our community, we develop, implement and oversee educational programs and workshops that promote environmentally sustainable behaviors among all age groups,
        with a particular emphasis on K-12 students.
      </p>
    </section>

    <aside>

    </aside>
  </main>
```

Comment: Seems alright to me...

Comment: How? The html for it is inside the body, but it appears outside it when you inspect it on the console

Comment: try add `display: inline-block;` for `main`, but you better not use floating rules in this case. Use flex.

Comment: It is si inside body, I dont know how you get other result, I just put it in my own host.

Comment: If the background color isn't the same as the elements above it, then it isn't in the body. Does it have a greenish background for you?

Comment: `float`ing elements are not considered by the browser when calculating height of block level parents. This is intended. Google **"clearfix"** and apply it to `main`. That being said, you should not try to use floats for page layout purposes. As your knowledge of CSS seems quite limited, using floats for layouting will run you into all sorts of problems you will neither understand nor be able to solve. Instead, make yourself familiar with `flexbox` and `grid` layouting.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code into a CodePen just to check, and the section is absolutely structured within the body of your html document. **The complication you are having with color has to do with you using the float property for the section element.** Of course float is a useful property, however it will result in unexpected behavior since you are manually moving the section and not letting the browser position the elements naturally.

In this case, if you are dead-set on keeping that position of the section element, and using float, you should just manually set the background color of that element to the same as the background color of the body. This will overlap the border of the body element, which can be fixed by adding a padding-bottom style to the body.

If it seems like a few band-aid solutions, that's because it is. **The float property is not designed to be used to create page layouts**, it's something that was only used because no other technologies were available. Now with CSS Grid and Flexbox, the float property should be reserved for wrapping text around images.

```css
body {
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}
section {
  background-color: #5cdb95;
}
```

Comment: While your post identifies the source of the problem, alot of its conclusions are both historically and factually wrong or inadequate.

Comment: This was my best attempt at giving an explanation given what I know. If you think something is incorrect, please educate me.

My source for the statement about how float should not be used for layout design is from a Kevin Powell video on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7gqJkdc5dM

Given his experience in frontend development, I take his word for it, plus my personal experience with all of the weird band-aids float needs to work properly (such as clearfix).